# Is there a way to capture dataset parameters in Azure Data Factory for Logging?

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

Is there a way I can capture the filename, which I have defined a dataset parameter? I want to capture it and store it in a log table.

[image]

Comment: Hi, how are you getting item().source_name? were you not able to use the same expression which you are using in filename property in the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You can create to stored procedure with filename parameter and insert file name into the log table using azure data factory and pass the same value/expression which you are currently passing in filename property of copy data activity under sink.

[image]

You can also use set variable activity to store the @item name into a variable and use it in later activities.

[image]